# Laravel 5 - Intervention Image Saving

Tags: php, laravel-5, intervention

I'm trying to create a working image upload in a form using Laravel 5 and Intervention.

```
    public function store()
    {
    $input = Request::all();
    Project::create($input);

    if (Input::hasFile('image'))
    {
        $file = Input::file('image');
        $file->move('uploads', $file->getClientOriginalName());

        $image = Image::make(sprintf('uploads/%s', $file->getClientOriginalName()))->resize(120, 120)->save();
    }

    return $file;

   // return redirect('projects');
}
```

It's copying the image in the specified folder but when I  return $file it gives me something in the lines of

> /tmp/phpoMwrrD

Instead of the file name.
I've been looking over the Intervention documentation, but can't find what I'm doing wrong.

Quoting the documentation;

> Handling image uploads in Laravel
>
> In a Laravel application it is also possible to pass an uploaded file
>   directly to the make method.
>
> Creating Image from File Upload in Laravel
>
> // resizing an uploaded file
>   Image::make(Input::file('photo'))->resize(300, 200)->save('foo.jpg');

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you return `$file`? Why don't you work with the `$image`?

Comment: @GladToHelp Updated OP with the entire function. I could work with $image, but in the progress of writing the function started using $file and didn't change. It shouldn't change the result of the function though.

Comment: The controller tries to convert the `$file` object to string, that is why you see the temporary name/path. You should take the filename from `$file->getClientOriginalName()`

Comment: Isn't that whats it doing here '$file->getClientOriginalName()))->resize(120, 120)->save();' or am I completely wrong on this one? It's resizing the file and saving the $file->getClientOriginalName() to the database, right? The sprintf is returning a formatted string, might that be the problem? I've been using http://www.phpgang.com/image-upload-and-resize-using-image-intervention-in-laravel_889.html as a tutorial for this.

Comment: your complaint was that:  "$file it gives me something in the lines of /tmp/phpoMwrrD instead of the file name." If you want the file name, get it from the string, don't output the whole $file object because Laravel will try to invoke toString() method on it, which in turn outputs the temp file/path. Maybe you want to achieve something else?

Comment: I see what you're saying. When I return $image, I suppose it really does return the entire image because I just get a page of weird symbols. It's also saving the /tmp/blabla to the database, which to me seems weird.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue thanks to @GladToHelp. Used

```
`$imageN = $file->getClientOriginalName();`
```

To retrieve the file name.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   if (Input::hasFile('image'))
{
    $file = Input::file('image');

    $image = Image::make($file)->resize(120, 120)->save('uploads/'.$file->getClientOriginalName());
}
```